# Is it possible to open particular screen of flutter app from another flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is it possible to open particular screen of flutter app from another flutter app ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of the firebase dynamic link.

Create dynamic links in both the app and launch the link with the help of launch `url_launcher`

Let us assume 2 flutter apps app A and B with N Number of pages.
For example, if you want to go to screen 2 of app A from B

you will call this function from the package `url_launcher` on App B

```
launch('https://yourapp.page.link/aL7u'); //dynamic link to open the screen.
```

This will launch a window that will redirect you to the page

to handle the dynamic link please refer to this document.

Flutter Dynamic Links:https://www.filledstacks.com/post/dynamic-links-in-flutter-a-complete-guide/

Navigation without Context:https://www.filledstacks.com/post/navigate-without-build-context-in-flutter-using-a-navigation-service/

`url_launcher`:https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Firebase Dynamic link documentation:https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links?authuser=0

Note: to implement this you must have access to both the apps and should implement dynamic links on both the

Comment: Thanks for your response, I go through with all stuff you said about but how can I generate the dynamic link for the another flutter app and open it from the current one ?

Comment: You can generate a dynamic link for the other app by creating a Firebase project if you don't already have a project for the other app and then you can generate a link in the dynamic link section (firebase console).
you can use the ```url_launcher``` package to open the link which in turn redirects you to the specific page in the second app provided the app is installed.

Note: If the second app is not yours this method will not work as I said you need access to both the apps.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I successfully completed it.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible!

add this package to your pubspec.yaml

flutter_sharing_intent: ^1.0.6 (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sharing_intent)

you can go through this package

Now! how you can open some specific Screen check the code below

```
_intentData =
        FlutterSharingIntent.instance.getMediaStream().listen((event) async {

      try {
        if (event.first.value.toString() != "") {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ShareIntentView(
                url: event.first.value.toString(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      }

      //print("Shared: getMedia ${event.map((f) => f.value).join(",")}");
    });
```